# .htaccess Set custom variables

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to set custom variables inside my .htaccess files so I could use them later in my .htaccess code ?

For example, I have a redirection to 2 different servers.

Can I store the servers URL and use the variable in my RewriteRule instead of writing the URL in the Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an environment variable via `RewriteRule`.

Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e for more details.

You can reference the environment variable in other mod_rewrite directives using `%{ENV:variable}`